# array index selection like in numpy but in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I have a 3x3 array:

```
var my_array = [[0,1,2],
                [3,4,5],
                [6,7,8]];
```

and want to get the first 2x2 block of it (or any other 2x2 block):

```
[[0,1], 
 [3,4]]
```

with numpy I would have written:

```
my_array = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
my_array[:2, :2]
```

to get the correct result.

I tried in javascript:

```
my_array.slice(0, 2).slice(0, 2);
```

but the second slice affects the first dimension, doing nothing.
Am I doomed to use for loop or is there some new ES6 syntax that would make my life simpler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use a combination of [`Array.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) and [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const input = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8]
];

const result = input.slice(0, 2).map(arr => arr.slice(0, 2));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.map()` and `.slice()` methods:

```js
var my_array = [[0,1,2],
                [3,4,5],
                [6,7,8]];
                
var result = my_array.slice(0, 2).map(a => a.slice(0, 2));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take objects for the indices and for the length of the wanted sub arrays.. Then slice and map the sliced sub arrays.

```js
var array = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]],
    length = { x: 2, y: 2 },
    indices = { i: 0, j: 0 },
    result = array.slice(indices.i, indices.i + length.x).map(a => a.slice(indices.j, indices.j + length.y));
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

It dont seems to a 3x# array , it is just array of arrays.

You can first use slice to get an array of only first two elements that is

```
[[0, 1, 2],[3, 4, 5]]
```

then use reduce to return a new array & inside it get only the first two values

```js
var my_array = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8]
];

let x = my_array.slice(0, 2).reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  acc.push(curr.slice(0, 2))
  return acc;
}, [])
console.log(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8]
];
let result =[]
input.forEach(([a, b], index) => {if(index < 2) result.push([a, b])})

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to work a lot with matrices, then you should check out [math.js](http://mathjs.org/docs/datatypes/matrices.html).

Try the following:

```
var my_array = [[0,1,2],
                [3,4,5],
                [6,7,8]];

var matrix = math.matrix(my_array);

var subset = matrix.subset(math.index([0, 1], [0, 1]));
```

Working [example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pxEJLJ).

Comment: I read that is it slow, not much but slower than doing it yourself. Is it true?

Comment: I have no records about its performance, but I think it should not be slower.